# How to print a javascript function result in HTML

Tags: javascript, string, html, function

I have a function where I want to print a string in html from a function in javascript that capitalizes every other letter in the string.

javascript:

```
function crazyCaps(s){
    let result =""
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        if (i%2 == 0){
            result += s[i].toLowerCase();
            else {
                result += s[i].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        console.log(result);
    }
    crazyCaps("helloworld");
    window.onload = crazyCaps();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src ="crazycaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    crazyCaps();

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [How to output stuff with javascript](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/javascript-output)

Comment: I think your code is missing some curly braces.  Second, you're assigning the *returned value* from your function as the window's `onload` handler.  Yet, your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but should work:

JS:

```
function crazyCaps(s){
    let result =""
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0){
            result += s[i].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            result += s[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerText=result;
}
window.onload = crazyCaps('helloworld');
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src ="crazycaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
          <div id="text"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `.innerText` is non-standard. Use `.textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.body.textContent += result` to write the result to the page. And you don't need to have a `window.onload` statement, you just need to the function:

```js
 

function crazyCaps(s) {
    let result =""
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            result += s[i].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            result += s[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    document.body.textContent += result;
}
crazyCaps("helloworld");
```

```html
 

<body></body>
```

Comment: `document.write()` should only be used when it has to be, which is when a new document is being created dynamically on the fly. If used incorrectly, it can overwrite the current document and cause it to be thrown out. When used correctly, you must build the output in a linear fashion, which is usually not possible. Instead, use the DOM API to populate/modify pre-existing DOM elements or create new ones as needed.

Comment: Sorry @ScottMarcus, will fix using `innerHTML `

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` when there's no HTML to read or write. It has performance and security implications. Use `.textContent` for non-HTML strings.

Comment: Okay - sorry again @ScottMarcus

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but right now your code produces the function on the web page. And, the way you have it, the results will always be added to the bottom of the page. What if the results need to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You have som small mistakes in your code you cant call javascript functions in between your html tags. writing crazyCaps(); just outputs "crazyCaps();" in plaintext. 
You need to return the string that you are creating and then assign that result to an element in your html, that can be done with `document.getElementById('IDGOESHERE').textContent`. 
Your if else sentence you need to structure it so the curlybracers ends and your else statement begins, `if (){} else{}` you had your else statement placed inside your if statement.

```js
function crazyCaps(s) {
  let result = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      result += s[i].toLowerCase();
    } else {
      result += s[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
document.getElementById('crazyoutput').textContent = crazyCaps("helloworld");
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="crazyoutput">
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zeonfrost/4q01x68z/1/

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` when there's no HTML to read or write. It has performance and security implications. Use `.textContent` for non-HTML strings.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are totally correct there are no reason to use innerHTML here, i have edited my answer to reflect your improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach is to set up an empty HTML element as a placeholder for the results to go in and then you populate that when needed. Also, you really don't need the `window.onload` event handler, just move the `<script>` to just before the `body` element closes. By that point, all the HTML has been parsed into the DOM and is ready to be interacted with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- JavaScript will access this element and populate it.-->
    <div id="results"></div>
    
    
    <!-- Placing the script just before the closing body tag ensures
         that by the time the parser reaches this point, all the HTML
         will have been read into memory. -->
    <script src ="crazycaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           
    <script>
      // Get a reference to the element where the output will go
      let output = document.getElementById("results");
      
      function crazyCaps(s){
        let result ="";
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
          if (i%2 == 0){
            result += s[i].toLowerCase();
          } else {
            result += s[i].toUpperCase();
          }
        }
        output.textContent = result;  // Populate the element
      }
      crazyCaps("helloworld");  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// INSIDE crazycaps.js

function crazyCaps(s){
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
      if (i%2 == 0){
         result += s[i].toLowerCase();
      } else {
         result += s[i].toUpperCase();
      }
    }
    return result;
    // the string is returned as a result
 }

console.log(crazyCaps("helloworld"));
// the console.log now occurs OUTSIDE of the crazyCaps function
    
window.onload = () => 
        document.body.textContent = crazyCaps( "example crazy capitals");
// window.onload is assigned to a CALL BACK FUNCTION, which is executed onload
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="crazycaps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would replace all the text in the `body` with the results of the function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What's the problem? `How to print a javascript function result in HTML`. document.body is an arbitrary element used, as a simple example, to `print a result in HTML`.

Comment: The problem is that your code would throw away everything else in the body. You don't think that's a problem? It's because of this that your answer is not how anyone would actually do this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Again, it's a simple example. The question has an empty body. I can literally say the same for your answer: `The problem is that your code would throw away everything else in the results container`. The author could easily take 2 seconds to replace `document.body` with another element.

Comment: No you couldn't?! My answer places the output in the specific element designed to receive it. Since your answer shows a way that isn't practical in any scenario and doesn't address a real-world way of solving the problem, it's not a good solution.

Comment: LOL. There is nothing copied from you or anyone else but the OP's original code in my answer. My answer was posted BEFORE yours! LOL

Comment: Do you really think taking text from a function named crazyCaps, and placing it in a div inside the main body is any more valid than this solution, for a *real-world scenario*.

Comment: Also, you're manipulating the DOM within a function used to generate crazyCap strings. Basic separation of concerns. Do you write code like this in your real world scenarios?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. Obviously, the OP and many others who will find this page don't understand how this works. Showing them a "sort of" answer and just assuming that they will understand that they really need to do it differently is not a very good assumption. Look, you can get mad and argumentative, or you can take my comments for what they are, simple constructive criticisms and hopefully learn something from them.

Comment: You have a problem with manipulating the DOM within a function? Where do ***you*** manipulate the DOM?

Comment: I think this answer is better than yours; so, you're pedantically trying to find faults in it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply: "Sorry @ScottMarcus, will fix using `document.getElementById("results")`"

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it like this:

```js
function crazyCaps(s) {
  let result = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      result += s[i].toLowerCase();
    } else {
      result += s[i].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  //Make sure to return your result instead of just logging it
  return result;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  this.body.textContent = crazyCaps('helloworld')
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This would replace all the text in the `body` with the results of the function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Hi Scott - I'll take a look at this when I get home. I thought that was OP desired functionality.

Answer (score -1):

```
function weird_string_format(string){
  let temp = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    temp += (i % 2 === 0) ? string[i] : string.charAt(i).toUpperCase() 
  }
  return temp;
}

document.write(temp);
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question is asking about.